# Proof of limits of a function in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Suppose  $f:(a,b) \rightarrow R$ , $p ⊆ [a,b]$ , and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) > 0$. Prove that there exists a $\delta > 0 $ such that $f(x) >0$ for all $x
> > ⊆(a,b)$ with $0 < |x-p| < \delta$

My approach:

Since $f:(a,b)$ is the open interval, $f$ should be include every interior point,
$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) > 0$. Then there should exist $L>0$ such as 
$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = L$ ( is there any relationship between *limit point* and *interior point*?)

Should $L$ be a limit point of $f$?

$L$ is a limit point, so there should be a $\delta >0$ in $f$
such that $0 < |L-p| < \delta$

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean '$x$ is a member of' rather than subset.

I won't give you the answer, but I will give you a sufficient hint:

Define the limit to be some value $L$ and define $\epsilon$ to be between $0$ and $L$.  In fact, $\epsilon$ being equal to $L/2$ works.  From there, use the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition to write your proof.  It should work out that way quite simply.

Comment: Please keep conversation out of answers. They are supposed to be of value to future readers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f:(a,b)\rightarrow \Bbb{R},\; p \in [a,b]$ accumulation point for $f$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow p}f(x)=\ell>0$. Prove that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in(a,b)$ and $x\neq p$ with $0 < |x-p| < \delta$.

We have to prove that there exists a neighbourhood $U(p)$ of $p$ such that $f$ is strictly positive on $U(p)\setminus\{p\}$.

Assume $\ell$ is finite, positive, and consider the neighbourhood $U_{\varepsilon}(\ell)$ of $\ell$ of radius $\varepsilon=\ell/2$. According to the definition, there is a neighbourhood $U(p)$ of $p$ satisfying
$$
\forall x\in\operatorname{dom}f,\; x\in U(p)\setminus\{p\} \Longrightarrow \;f(x)\in U_{\varepsilon}(\ell).
$$
As $U_{\varepsilon}(\ell)=\left(\frac{\ell}{2},\frac{3\ell}{2}\right)\subset (0,+\infty)$, all the values $f(x)$ are positive.

If $\ell=+\infty$ it sufficies to take a neighbourhood $U_{N}(\ell)=(N,+\infty)$ of $+\infty$ with $N>0$ and use the corresponding definition of limit.

Similar results hold when $\ell<0$ or $\ell=-\infty$.